# StreamWriter Insufficient Privileges With UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, exception, streamwriter

I am using the following code to write a file to the Desktop.

```
string submittedFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
int i = 0;
StreamWriter sw = null;
sw = new StreamWriter(submittedFilePath, false);

for (i = 0; i < PSOLib.table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sw.Write(PSOLib.table.Columns[i].ColumnName + ";");
}

sw.Write(PSOLib.table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
sw.WriteLine();

foreach (DataRow row in PSOLib.table.Rows)
{
    object[] array = row.ItemArray;

    for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(array[i].ToString() + ";");
    }

    sw.Write(array[i].ToString());
    sw.WriteLine();
}

sw.Close();
```

However whenever I try to invoke the method I get:

```
Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop' is denied. 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException.
```

Comment: I have checked the privileges. They are as expected.

Comment: You are writing to a folder here, while you should be writing to a file..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't specify a file for your `StreamWriter`, but a folder.

This should do it:

```
string submittedFilePath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\myFile.txt.";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was struggling so much to understand why it wasn't working. I can't up vote this enough! even years later, you're still helping :)